# Rest API Requests drop on Django framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, waitress

There are some web services developed in python and Django framework in Windows server

Also, [Waitress](https://pypi.org/project/django-waitress/) serves Django
In addition, Nginx has chosen as a web server, but Django is not served on Nginx

there are some problems when users are more than 80 per seconds

First of all: Requests not queued and receive sadly and periodic (It seems they are buffering)

Second: Many requests dropped

`Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Comment: Why use `Waitress`? A `backlog` argument can be passed to waitress to define the number of incoming connections that can be queued up

Comment: case of windows server, ``Waitress``` chosen instead of uwsgi and GUnicorn @IainShelvington